# Azure Devops Deploy asp.net website(not webapp)

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to configure Azure DevOps to deploy code (website) from git repository to my on premise server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASP.NET Website you should first pushed the entire code from local to Azure DevOps.

Then create a Build Definition in Azure DevOps to build your project.

Some steps for your reference:

1. Install [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) since you want to deploy app to your web server

2        .  Add Windows Machine File Copy step to copy files to your web server

[image]

4. Add WinRM-IIS Web App Management step to create or update web site in IIS

[image]

5. Add WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment step to deploy app to web site (step 4)

[image]

You could also take a look at this thread: [Automated Deployement of ASP.Net MVC Website In IIS server with a Continuous Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930875/automated-deployement-of-asp-net-mvc-website-in-iis-server-with-a-continuous-dep?noredirect=1#comment69274018_40930875)