# Azure DevOps Pipelines setup for onsite servers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, windows-server-2012-r2

Hello fellow developers

I have run into a problem (surprise, eh?). In our company we are in the process of switching our GitHub repos to Micrsoft Azure since we have bought licenses for MSDN, SharePoint, etc. etc. etc.

Like so many before us, we have an ASP.NET Framwork MVC application, we would like to set up a pipeline in Azure for, so that we can have a flow in our development process. This would work so well if we had servers in the cloud or access to it from anywhere other than our own network. The servers of course expose them selves in some ways, since they host web applications on an URL, but that's it.

The applications we run are managed and served by `IIS Manager`. The server I'm working on now is a `Windows Server 2012R2`

Is there any way that the internet knows that I can expose the server to our Azure DevOps setup so that I can make pipelines for deployment and make my life **SO** much easier.

**EDIT**: It just occurs to me that I can make a PowerShell script that I can run on the server after DevOps have made a build and a release? Or am I in the wrong here?

**EDIT2:** answer given below.

Comment: You don't need to expose the server, you need to install an agent on your network which can poll DevOps for new deployment jobs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to connect azure pipelines to on premise servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561448/is-it-possible-to-connect-azure-pipelines-to-on-premise-servers)

Comment: @ADyson - very possible :) I am new to Azure so all information is both confusing and exciting :D

Comment: I'm new to Azure too. I haven't actually done any of this stuff yet (although we do plan to do something with automated builds), I just searched online for a few seconds :-)

Comment: @ADyson - yeah, I tried to search too but I didn't know the correct terms at the time. So all my results were bogus to say the least :P

Comment: ah ok. I simply searched "azure pipeline on premises". Usually the simpler your search is the better the results.

Comment: indeed. I tried something in the line of "Azure Deploy to onsite server IIS Manager ......." - ya, know... way too complicated :P

Comment: @IncrediblePony Hi,Do you check the way given by Andy?Is it helpful to you?If you have any question,please feel free to ask.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT - I have made a basic setup that works :) but I was not assigned more time at work for now to dive further into it at the moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way that the internet knows that I can expose the server to our Azure DevOps setup so that I can make pipelines for deployment and make my life SO much easier.

The simplest way is deploying a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install) on that server or any other machines which located in the same local network (same LAN)  with the onsite server. Thus the agent can access and deploy the project to the onsite server. So, in your scenario you can setup the agent on the `Windows Server 2012R2` server.

To deploy self-hosted agents please refer to [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for details.

After that, you just need to create a build and release pipeline and set CI/CD to deploy the application by using the self-hosted agent.

For the ASP.NET MVC application deployment you can reference the following threads:

- [Build and deploy an ASP.NET core app running on IIS using Azure
  pipelines](https://medium.com/@taithienbo/build-and-deploy-an-asp-net-core-app-running-on-iis-using-azure-pipelines-e675041f62d4)
- [Automated Deployement of ASP.Net MVC Website In IIS server with a Continuous Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930875/automated-deployement-of-asp-net-mvc-website-in-iis-server-with-a-continuous-dep)

You can reference below blog and video if you want to deploy the application to Azure, thus you can access the application from anywhere:

- [Create a CI/CD pipeline for .NET with the Azure DevOps Project](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiFjDeSV6jQ